# Stop scrollbar appearing when <div> element is sliding up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to make a sliding function. When the `<div>` element slides up, scrollbars appear due to the command, `overflow:auto`, which creates a scrollbar when the text overflows the `<div>`. However, in the instance of sliding, I do not want this to occurr.

How do I stop the scrollbar appearing when the user toggles the content sliding up and down?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use 'overflow: none'
2. In the toggle-function, you can set overflow to none by writing `$(element).css('overflow', 'none')` before the toggle action, and back again by writing `$(element).css('overflow', 'auto')` when the action is over.

Comment: $(".expandcollapse").click(function() {
        
        $(".content").css('overflow', 'none');
        $(".content").slideToggle(600);
        $(".content").css('overflow', 'auto');
    });

After adding both lines, the problem isn't solved.

Comment: $(".content").css('overflow', 'none'); $(".content").slideToggle(600).done(){ $(".content").css("overflow", "hidden"); }